# Include and use NPM Libraries in Angular with Angular-CLI

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I am trying to use the **progressbar.js** library from npm in my Angular 2 application which uses Angular-CLI.

I installed it with `npm install progressbar.js --save`. The documentation of progressbar.js says to use it with `var ProgressBar = require('progressbar.js')`, which I can't use because I don't have SystemJS.

I searched a bit and found a solution to include it in the scripts array of the angular-cli.json, which I did:

```
"scripts": [
     "../node_modules/progressbar.js/dist/progressbar.js"
  ],
```

The application compiles fine with `ng serve`, but I really couldn't figure how to make use of the included library. In my component I tried different import statements like `import * as Progressbar from 'progressbar.js/dist'` or `import { Progressbar } from 'progressbar.js/dist'` but didn't get any of them to work.

Does anyone know how I can use this library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since ProgressBar is not exported as a TypeScript class you will not be able to use the `import` statement to import it into your component.

After including the progressbar.js file in the scripts array of angular-cli.json, it enough to add the following line in the components where you need to use it: `declare var ProgressBar: any;`. This statement is a workaround which enables using third party JavaScript libraries in a TypeScript class.

Example app.component.js - simply printing the object in the console:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var ProgressBar: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app works!';

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(ProgressBar);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it and it works... Just trying to understand now how I can figure out which variable name to declare for an abitrary library. Obviously `ProgressBar` in this case is an easy guess but I'm sure there is a better way then guessing... Was just now looking through some files in the `node_modules` but could find an obvious declaration, export, configuration, ...

Comment: @DanielLerps Usually these JavasScript libraries add a reference to an object (ProgressBar in your case) to either the `window` or the `global` object. If you open up the progressbar.js file you can see how this reference is added, although the code is not very readable.